# Finding a vector not in the kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix that looks like below,

\begin{align}
D = \begin{pmatrix} -3 && -9 \\ 1 && 3 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Clearly, $\det(D) = 0$, and D is an nilpotent matrix of index $2$. Now I want to find at least one vector u that satisfies $Du ≠ 0$, once u is found, I would like to find a specific matrix Q and its inverse $Q$ based on the following rules.

\begin{align}
  f_1 = u \\
  f_2 = Du \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  f_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \\
  f_2 = \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  Q = (f_1 f_2) = \begin{pmatrix} a && c \\ b && d \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

If I write down Du ≠ 0,

\begin{align}
   Du = \begin{pmatrix} -3 && -9 \\ 1 && 3 \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{pmatrix} \ne \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Then, the vector that meets the condition is

\begin{align}
  u \ne s\begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

However, I am not sure how to use the vector to construct $Q$.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The vector $u = e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ works so why bother searching every vector that works?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Does that mean there are infinite many u that could be used to construct Q, and I just need to find an arbitrary one u that satisfies?

Comment: Yes, the kernel has dimension $1$ which is very small in a dimension $2$ space, take randomly any vector and it will fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use $e_1$ as you vector $u$, you have
$$De_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
-3\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$
With your definition,
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1&-3\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$Q^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1&3\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I think you want to change the basis from (e_1,e_2) to $(e_1,De_1)$ to do so you compute $Q D Q^{-1}$ you'll find
$$QDQ^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is a canonical way to see a nilpotent matrix of order $2$.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive process. It is quite easy to understand.

Comment: I think the -3 in inverse Q should be 3.

Comment: yes I mistyped thank you for noticing

Comment: If you want to comprehend things like that, think about matrices as linear function that act on basis, $D$ is the function that sends $e_1$ to $(-3 \cdot e_1 + 1 \cdot e_2)$ and $e_2$ to $(-9\cdot e_1+3\cdot e_2)$, but if you change the basis for $(e_1,De_1)$, it will send $e_1$ to $(0 \cdot e_1 + 1 \cdot De_1) = De_1$ and $De_1$ to $(0 \cdot e_1 + 0 \cdot De_1) = 0$. Which gives you in the first case your matrix and in the second case, a more suitable form for your matrix (the one at the end).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I noticed the linear function(transformation) as you said with D and this is related to the change of basis. I might need to review what I have learned regarding changing basis, it is sometimes a bit hard to visualize in my brain.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, much easier to solve $D\vec{u} = \vec{0}$ and take any other vector.

So take something easy that does not satisfy $Du= 0$, e.g. $u = (1,0)^T$. Then, What is $Du$ and what does $Q$ look like?

Answer (score 1):

You find a vector $f_1=u$, and $Du\neq0$. You want to find another vector $f_2=Du$, which is linearly independent to $u$. We know $f_2=Du\in\text{Im}D$ and $\dim\text{Im}D=1$, hence you can choose any vector $u$, such that $u\notin \text{Im}D\land u\notin \ker D$, for example, let $u=(1,0)^T$